# Find where dependencies are coming from in Python?

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools, pip

When I run `pip install .` I get all dependencies installed, including transitive dependencies, but the problem is that there are two modules that depend on two different versions of lxml. How can I figure out who is requiring what with `pip` or any other tool?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an idea of which modules depend on lxml? If so, you could simply check those modules setup.py files and check `install_requires`, and most package creators will include the version number as well. e.g.

```
  install_requires=[
    'django-modeldict>=1.1.6',
    'nexus>=0.1.7',
    'django-jsonfield',
  ],
```

From: https://github.com/disqus/gargoyle/blob/master/setup.py

You may also want to look into something like [modulefinder](http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html) but I think simply checking the setup.py is much easier in this case.